# Nodered+external html with JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, node-red

I have an external report.html file which contain also JavaScript.
This JavaScript has a lot of variables which contain a lot of values. (Mb in plain text)
At the end is taken and render to the nice table. But I need take this variables out from the report.html to the Node-red and process them there.

I tried to load the file and print it out by  but it did not do the JavaScript function inside.

Do I have somehow read the variable as an variable in node-red?

Of course I could do the parser and process through whole document and parse it manually but it is tuns of work in case it is possible to just load it somehow.

Comment: Node-RED is no different from any other programming environment, it doesn't offer anything special to magically extract value from a remote website. Assuming the values are all inline in the page your only option is to parse the page. But without a lot more detail in the question (e.g. a minimal example of the page) it is impossible to say any more.

Comment: Thank you  for comment. It is not an webpage. It is just html file. It mean, I can read all the content with scripts etc. Here is the example [link](https://pastebin.com/HS3ibDfx) I need execute the main function to fill the data into variables and then read those variables. I dont want to magically extract value. I am talking about the same programing language, just I ask, for some posibility how to execute it by node-red. :-D As I understand it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Given that your html is already loaded as string in `msg.payload` and your javascript code is bounded by `<script>` and `</script>` tags, you can first parse your html by:

```
var jsCode = msg.payload.split("<script>").pop().split("</script>")[0];
```

And then to run the code represented in `jsCode` string use `eval()` function:

```
eval(jsCode);
```

Your environment will act as it was written in editor and executed by you, so you should have access to all vars and functions declared in the inline js code.

##### Disclaimer

Actually it is not safe to use `eval()` [SEE WHY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!), but for your case maybe it's the best solution.

Comment: Hi Dawid, Thank you. I already used previous solution but your propose looks very good. I will try to learn more about that. :-)